# Реализация функции выбора нужного драйвера видеокарты

Tags: c++, компиляция, линковка

Мне было необходимо выбрать драйвер видеокарты для рендеринга, в доке нашел решение по этому вопросу

```
extern "C"
{__declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 1;
}
```

После я захотел написать функцию, при помощи которой в начале функции `main` я могу передать в неё числа 0 или 1, встроенная или дискретная соответственно. Как такую функцию можно реализовать? После решил сделать по-другому: пытался делать это при помощи условной компиляции в .h файле, но понял, что не понимаю, как из `*.cpp` файла "передать" в `*.h` файл, например, `DISCRETE`. Если же просто сделать `#define DISCRETE` после
`#pragma once` в файле `*.h`, как потом поменять на `INTEGRATED`? Каждый раз менять в `*.h`? Что-то мне подсказывает, что это не так должно работать. Заранее спасибо.

```
//myHeader.h
#pragma once
#ifdef DISCRETE

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 1;
}
#endif

#ifdef INTEGRATED

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 0;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Для выбора у вас должно быть два разных исполняемых файла - один с AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance, а другой - без.

Comment: @user7860670, я создал две сборки в проекте, в одной сборке сделал AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 0, в другой AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 1, вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: Именно так 1234